# Is there a way to override what useMemo does to determine if there's a change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

`useMemo(() => expensiveFunction(), [deps])` re-executes the expensiveFunction when the deps have changed.  I was wondering... is there a way to control how React will check if the deps have changed?

I would like to see if I can do a "deep" isEqual check of the dependencies rather than the shallow check much like what I did with using useReducer to implement useDeepState

```
import isEqual from "lodash.isequal";
import { Dispatch, useReducer } from "react";
/**
 * This is similar to the `React.useState` function except it uses
 * [lodash.isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) to perform a
 * deep comparison of the values.
 * @param initialState initial state
 * @returns state, setter
 * @category React State
 */
export function useDeepState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<S>] {
  function newStateIfNotEqual(state: S, newState: S) {
    return isEqual(state, newState) ? state : newState;
  }
  if (typeof initialState === "function") {
    return useReducer(
      newStateIfNotEqual,
      null as unknown as S,
      initialState as () => S
    );
  } else {
    return useReducer(
      newStateIfNotEqual,
      initialState
    );
  }
}
```

https://github.com/trajano/react-hooks/blob/master/src/useStates/useDeepState.ts

Comment: Maybe https://dev.to/vsramalwan/ways-to-handle-deep-object-comparison-in-useeffect-hook-1elm

Comment: You cant override but you just can implement it by yourself with a custom hook, there are many such examples.